# Как остановить процесс использования видео/аудио файла?

Tags: python

Есть функция, которая обрезает видео. После ее завершения нужно переименовывать файл, при сохранении файла я сделать это не могу, так как тогда портиться файл. Для переименовывания файл, я предварительно удаляю исходный файл, а потом уже переименовываю созданный файл. Но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

```
  File "D:\video\test_program.py", line 72, in <module>
   os.remove(video_name)
  PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'video_1.mp4'
```

Как можно завершить процесс использования видео.
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
    video_maker_function.cut_video(video_name, start, end, old_name_video, user_id)
    os.remove(video_name)
    os.rename('res_' + str(old_name_video) + '.mp4', video_name)
```

Для обрезания видео я использовал библиотеку moviepy

Comment: Попробуйте подождать перед удалением сколько-то, если это приемлемо: `time.sleep(10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В библиотеки, которая используется есть метод close(). Он закрывает процесс использующий видео файл.